# Java: set and get methods for strings

Tags: java, class, object

I have to write a program which uses appropriate get and set methods to output the following:
This person is John Smith (21, male)

So far, I have reached here:

```
public class Person {

    private int age;
    private String name;
    private String gender;

    public void setAge(int age){

        this.age= age;
    }

    public int getAge(){

        return age;
    }

    public void setName(String thename){

        this.name=name;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender){
        this.gender= gender;
    }

    public String getGender(){

        return gender;
    }

    public void person(){

        System.out.printf("This person is %s(%d, %s)", getName(), getAge(), getGender());
    }
```

}

In the main class:

```
class MyClass{


        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Person personObj1= new Person();

            String thisname= "John Smith";

            personObj1.setName(thisname);

            personObj1.setAge(21);

            String thisgender= "male";

            personObj1.setGender(thisgender);

            personObj1.person();


        }


    }
```

The problem is that I am getting errors like *The method setName(String) is undefined for the type Person* for the set methods in the main.
I am still a beginner in Java so I have yet to get the hang of it.

Comment: Try saving all your files. I see nothing wrong with the syntax you have. Do you have multiple `Person` types? Are you using the right one?

Comment: Btw, you intend to do this in `setName` method: `this.name=thename;`

Comment: Thank you so much. Actually, I had not saved the Person class..the program is working now except that it's printing _This person is null(21, male)_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only problem I see is in the implementation of `setName` itself. You don't use the input variable `thename` at all.

```
public void setName(String thename){

    this.name=name;
}
```

The last line should be

```
this.name = thename;
```

But this would not give you the error you say you got (that `setName` doesn't exist). I'm guessing you either defined the actual method with all lowercase (like `public void setname(String thename)`) or we are not seeing all of the code.

Comment: Yeah, actually I mistyped it.. had to write _public void setName(String name)_ but instead wrote _thename_ I got that error because I didn't save the other file(the Person class).. Thank you..

Comment: This is why it can be quite useful to write method parameters using a certain style. I usually denote parameters with a lower case 'p', i.e. `pName`, and assign it to a member variable like `mName`. This can help prevent confusion.